# Issues Updating Andorid Application Due to Version Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having issues publishing issues.

This is my *second* update, so I assumed I would just need to increment each of the following as seen below **which have already been incremented**:

[image: Version Number]

Despite the incrementation, I am running into this issue seen below:

[image: Error Uploading]

Comment: Increase `versionCode`, not only `versionName`  . Please see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload an APK to the Play Store with a versionCode you have already used for a previous version.

In  build.gradle  file you have to change inside defaultConfig  versionCode and versionName.

for example:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.example"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

For more detail follow this link https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

Comment: Shoot, looks like I missed the update within the Gradle defaultConfig. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is saying you uploaded an apk with **VersionCode 2**, which is already used previously.

So, Before releasing an app to the play store you must update the **android:versionCode**. Basically, the version code should be unique on each release.

So, if you didn't updated the **android:versionCode**, please update it with a new unique number and then build another apk and upload.

If you updated the versionCode and it's still happening, make sure you are uploading the corrected APK to the play console.

Comment: Are you updating the version code from the _app/build.gradle_ file? 

If not please update those from there.